# When do web browsers send the Origin Header to the same domain?

Tags: javascript, security, csrf

I'm aware of [this CORS support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS), but I have a simpler question: regardless of whether CORS is in use or not, when will web browsers include the Origin header in requests to the *same* domain? Which browser versions? e.g., IE 9+, Chrome 20+, etc.